# Nested jquery submit function not firing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax once a user has clicked on an image element.

HTML

```
        <img class="remove_subscription" id="remove_mobile_id_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/ic_remove_circle_outline_grey600_24dp.png" alt="sms remove icon"/>
          <form class="hidden" id="remove_user_mobile_form_ajax_54" method="POST" action="#">
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="followed_user_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LEAVE LIST"/>
          </form>
```

JS

```
$(".remove_subscription").click(function(){
    $("#remove_user_mobile_form_ajax_54").submit(function(event){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

I can't get the alert or any of the submit function code to fire. I've got other forms working fine but they're submitted when a user clicks the submit button element, the only real difference is that now I'm submitting when a user clicks an image element outside of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not submitting the form, you are just registering a submit event handler.

If you want to submit the form, just call the submit method without any parameter.

```
$(".remove_subscription").click(function(){
    $("#remove_user_mobile_form_ajax_54").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#remove_user_mobile_form_ajax_54").submit(function(){
    alert("test");
});

$(".remove_subscription").click(function(){
    $("#remove_user_mobile_form_ajax_54").submit();
});
```